# IValueConverter does not pick up a change in bound collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid with comboboxes in the headers to use as filters and I want to have all the distinct values in the respective column in the header combobox.

Therefore I thought I should use a IValueConverter and bind the same collection has the datagrid has to each header and just filter out the correct values and return them.

The problem is that the value converter is only accessed once on startup and never again eventhough the collection changes.

The bound collection is an observablecollection.

The datagrid items, bound to the same collection, updates.

This is the xaml for the combobox

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Issues, Converter={StaticResource DataGridFilterableValueConverter},ConverterParameter="Madeby"} SelectionChanged="FilterComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

The IValueConverter is added as a resource to the window.

Am I missing something about the IValueConverter? Shouldnt it act like a filter that the collection is run through each time it needs to fetch a value?

I have been testing the IValueConverter for a few weeks now and I can never seem to get it to run more than once eventhough the collection changes.

I dont know if there is anything else I can write to point you to my error.

Thank you in advance!

/Erik

Comment: This approach won't work because a change in the bound collection fires an `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event, which will not trigger the binding to the `Issues` property (which would be triggered by the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event). You may want to take a look at the [How to: Filter Data in a View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752348.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Ok, does that make sense? 
The itemssource on the datagrid get notified when the collection changes, but not the IValueConverter? 
Anyway, I hooked on the collectionchanged event of the collection and raised the propertychanged event for the property when the collection was changed and it worked. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Converter` code will be called when you will notify the `Issues` property. So try to notify `Issue` property whenever you are adding/removing any item to that collection. I think it should work.

Comment: Yup, excellent. But I dont like the logic:
why doesnt it get called when the collection changes like a normal binding?

Comment: Here we are using `converter` with `Issues` property, so for sure `Converter` will be called each time `Issues` property will be changed and will be notified. But as the `Issues` property is collection type, it doesn't change the `Issues` property when we add/remove any item. So that's why it is not notified and `Converter` is not called.